# Use Request with NASA data on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, request, google-colaboratory

i am trying to use Request to download lot of liks from NASA Data Access, but i am getting `error code 401`, probably because i could not made the authentication. Actually, i have a .netrc file that contains the code `machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login <uid> password <password>` but i don´t know how Google Colaboratory recognize and run the .netrc file that allow to download the files.

the code that i am trying to use is:

```
  URL = rutas_GPM.iloc[i,0]
   
  # Set the FILENAME string to the data file name, the LABEL keyword value, or any customized name. 
  FILENAME = 'GPM{0}.nc'.format(i)
  result = requests.get(URL)
  try:
    result.raise_for_status()
    f = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Prueba/"+FILENAME,'wb')
    f.write(result.content)
    f.close()
    print('contents of URL written to '+FILENAME)
  except:
    print('requests.get() returned an error code '+str(result.status_code))
```

can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Colaboratory use a virtual enviroment based on Linux, in this order, you have to follow the instructions sugested by NASA for MAC/Linux:

```
cd $HOME
touch .netrc
echo "machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login <uid> password <password>" >> .netrc
chmod 0600 .netrc
```

`<uid>` is your NASA ID and `<password>` is your password account.

further, you have to upload in the "home" and "root" folder (on the colab enviroment), the .netrc file that you created previously in Windows OS, on your PC. then, you run the code and start to download the files.

Comment: If I'm using Windows, where should I save the file? I'm having the same issue where I have the .netrc file with the required credentials but I'm still unable to get the data. I tried saving the file in C:/Users/xyz/.netrc and also in C:/Users\.netrc but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, running a cell at the start of your Google Colab script with the following seems to have solved the same issue for me. This puts the .netrc file in the /root directory for your Google Colab session.

```
!touch /root/.netrc
!echo "machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login <uid> password <pwd>" >> /root/.netrc
!chmod 0600 /root/.netrc
```

I was then successful in downloading data using the following cells. The first installs the PODAAC library for downloading data from EarthData.

```
pip install podaac-data-subscriber
```

The second downloads a week of SST data (and uses the /root/.netrc file to get the credentials).

```
!podaac-data-downloader -c MUR-JPL-L4-GLOB-v4.1 -d ./data --start-date 2023-11-28T21:00:00Z --end-date 2023-12-03T21:00:00Z -e .nc
```

The downloaded data will be in /content/data/.